# Point Set Shape Detection: save planar shapes to file

Tags: cgal

Although I don't know how to write C++ I am trying to use CGAL for trying to derive building shapes from LiDAR point clouds using Point Set Shape Detection. Using the examples I can read points and normals from a file, whereupon CGAL detects shapes. The program is set to detect only planar shapes.

I would like to save the planar shapes to a file, so that I can use them in other software. But I was unable to find examples of how that can be achieved. The test program I use is based on the [efficient_RANSAC_parameters.cpp](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Point_set_shape_detection_3/Point_set_shape_detection_3_2efficient_RANSAC_parameters_8cpp-example.html) code. It has a part when it iterates through all detected shapes. Could it be possible to add something there that will write the planar shapes to a file? I see the OFF format is a popular and simple way (in CGAL) to save polygons to a file, so that could be a good candidate file format.

Comment: OFF is used to represent meshes, here you want to save planes to use them in another software. The format is imposed by what the other software is able to read.

Comment: I have noticed that there is sufficient support for OFF in other software. But any other non-binary format would be OK, as I could use text processing to derive other formats. I would just like to have a file I can work with. Any way of writing the shape coordinates to a text file line by line would work for me.

Answer (score 1):

A colleague who does know how to write C++ has helped me with this problem. He came up with the following:

```
while (it != shapes.end()) {
  if (Plane* plane = dynamic_cast<Plane*>(it->get()))
  {
    std::cout << "PLANE_" << count++ << "[" << std::endl;
    const std::vector<size_t> indices = it->get()->indices_of_assigned_points();
    std::vector<size_t>::const_iterator iti = indices.begin();
    while (iti != indices.end()) {
      // Retrieves point
      Point_with_normal pw = *(points.begin() + (*iti));
      Kernel::Point_3 p = pw.first;
      std::cout << "POINT[" << p.x() << "," << p.y() << "," << p.z() << "]" << std::endl;
      // Proceeds with next point.
      iti++;
    }
    std::cout << "]" << std::endl;
  }
  // Proceeds with next detected shape.
  it++;
}
```

This block can replace loop in the efficient_RANSAC_parameters.cpp example. The output looks like this:

```
PLANE_0[
POINT[34.96,584.49,0.47]
POINT[34.97,585.24,0.54]
POINT[34.88,584.51,0.49]
POINT[34.98,584.75,0.49]
]
```

That gives me something to work with. In my case, I use sed to transform this output to SQL insert queries that allow me to transfer the data to a relational database for further processing.

Answer (score 0):

In the [example](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Point_set_shape_detection_3/index.html#title5) in the user manual you can see that once you have a plane shape object
`if(Plane* plane = dynamic_cast<Plane*>(it->get())){..}` you can obtain from the plane shape object a `CGAL::Plane_3`, from which you can obtain a point and a normal, or the coefficients of the plane.

Comment: Thanks, but my problem was that I did not know how to write the properties of the plane to a file. But I have found help, see my answer below.